# Obtaining PIL instead of Pillow for Python 2.7 64-bit on Windows

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, python-imaging-library

Pillow for Python seems to be completely broken. Every image produces an `IOError: cannot identify image file`. Using Python 2.6 (where I had PIL installed) works great. Does anyone know where to get hold of `PIL-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7.exe` now that http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ has moved on to only offering Pillow?

**EDIT:** Please note that PIL 1.1.7 on Python 2.7 using Windows 64-bit is confirmed working when opening the same files, we just cannot find the installer.

Comment: On my system Pillow-2.2.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe passes all self tests and many third party packages using Pillow test OK too. It does not seem broken. Please report your specific issue at https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues?state=open

Comment: I will do, there is not enough time at the moment (short deadline to produce a lot of graphics) to file a good bug report. Solid advice though. Broken is a harsh word for me to have used.

Comment: The big problem with Pillow is that there are other packages that only work with PIL and are incompatible with Pillow.  Anyone found a place where PIL is still available?

Comment: @ChrisDodd 1.1.7 is the last version of PIL. [win32 here](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). [win64 here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: @Pylyp: unfortunately that link only has win64 binaries for python2.5, not 2.7

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here you can find [PIL-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7.exe](https://github.com/lightkeeper/lswindows-lib/blob/master/amd64/python/PIL-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7.exe?raw=true)

Comment: If you get registry error, see here: https://avaminzhang.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/python-version-2-7-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry/ I copied with cmd: reg copy

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://christianakesson.com/2013/4615) blog by Christian explains process of compiling PIL for 64 bit Python in Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2010. At end of the blog, zip file containing compiled files for PIL and dependencies is also provided

Answer (score 0):

Install Pillow or PIL from repository (option 1 or 2). I would recommend you to use Pillow instead of PIL. If options 1 and 2 would not help use option 3.
You don't need a separate installer for windows.

1. To install for Windows you can use easy_install:

   `easy_install Pillow`
2. or pip

   `pip install Pillow`
3. or just get Pillow source from [Pillow repository](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow)
   unpack and run

   `python setup.py install`

Online help for Pillow is [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Pillow is broken on 64 bit Windows (not on 32 bit) whereas PIL works beautifully. I need to use 64 bit to deal with RAM limits. Thanks though. I have tried the version from the site mentioned and using pip/easy_install with a compile chain. Same issue.